# X-axis labels overlaps in react-native svg-charts

Tags: react-native, charts

I am using react-native-svg-charts to show pie charts and bar charts 
in react-native, in bar charts, X-axis labels overlap or doesn't display.

[image: lables in X-axis overlaps as shown in image]

how can render text content in X-axis in bar charts

this is my code

```
<XAxis
  style={{flex:1,height: windowSize.width/1.875, paddingTop:10 }}
  data={data2}
  formatLabel={value => {
   return data2.map(item => {
      return `${item}\n`;
          });
        }}
   contentInset={{ left: 30, right: 30 }}
   svg={{ fontSize: 10, fill: '#3A8F98' }}
   />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<XAxis
   style={{ paddingTop: 10,backgroundColor:'red' }}
   data={data}
   formatLabel={(value, index) => this.state.data2[index]}
   contentInset={{ left: 18, right: 18 }}
   svg={{ fontSize: windowSize.width/55, fill: '#3A8F98' }}/>
```

changed the formatLabel from

```
formatLabel={value => {return data2.map(item => {
  return `${item}\n`;
      });
    }}
```

to

```
formatLabel={(value, index) => this.state.data2[index]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate the labels using the `rotation` svg attribute.

```js
<XAxis
  data={data}
  svg={{ rotation: 30 }}
/>
```

Comment: if i use svg={{ rotation: 30 }} iam getting like this.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iz14Wm1o5n4eTGuJTnJPf39E8U9aNwNZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like each of the label is the same and contains the whole set of labels

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `formalLabel`?

Comment: i want to show labels in bar charts as in image link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FPd6uT8VcDfK4aU4rGPd3yFy7kSug95o/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you can just remove the property and use the default value which is `formatLabel={x => x}`. Right now you are sending the whole `data2` set to each label.